# Generate map on android button click

Tags: android, maps

I did so much research on this. Found out a few tutorials. There were so many errors and later I found out that "Map views do not work with  v2 API."...So all my hard work gave me no result at the end of the day.

Can someone please tell me how to display a map on click of a button..?